# BLE connect() to gatt server works with one "peripheral" app but not with mine

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building an android app to make BLE payments (contactless payments). I have two apps to build : One which will play the role of the gatt server ( advertising and providing services with characteristics), and the other one to scan advertising devices, connect to the first one and start a request.

My problem is that when i call connectGatt on my scanned device object, i get a callback after about 40 sec with STATE_DISCONNECTED and status 133.

I researched a lot on this forum and others, and at the beginning i tought problem was coming from the scanning app, with all known problems (adding delay before calling connectGatt()/ run calls on main Thread...)

But finally i used my scanning app with a BLE peripheral test app found on the play store and i went well in the callback with STATE_CONNECTED and i was able to discover services.

So my question is, why my BLE peripheral app (which start a gatt server and start advertising) is not reachable by others with connectGatt ? And why however advertising packets are well detected ? I have to precise that when i start my gatt server, onServiceAdded callback is working fine.

How i start my gatt server :

```
  public void startGattServer(){
    bluetoothGattServer = bluetoothManager.openGattServer(this, bluetoothGattServerCallback);
    BluetoothGattService service = new BluetoothGattService(UUID.fromString(GattAttributes.APDUSERVICE), BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic apduRequestCharacteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
            UUID.fromString(GattAttributes.APDUREQUEST),
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic apduResponseCharacteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
            UUID.fromString(GattAttributes.APDURESPONSE),
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);
    service.addCharacteristic(apduRequestCharacteristic);
    service.addCharacteristic(apduResponseCharacteristic);
    bluetoothGattServer.addService(service);
  }
```

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: I just tried to run a gatt server with a test app found on Github and i'm still unable to connect this server with BLE scanner app (play store). I don't understand...

Comment: I finally reached successfully my gatt server by moving the code from a separate Service class to my Activity class (even if functions to manage gatt server are in an external class, if an instance is created in the activity, and functions to use gatt server are called from that instance in the activity it works too). So it appears that if you run your gatt server functions from a Class which extends Service, bugs can appears to reach the server

Comment: Finally i was able to make everything works even within a Service, i still don't understand exactly what was going wrong but i started from a working code found on GitHub and now everything is OK. If you want to start too from that code : https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver/tree/master/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/gattserver